# How to reference both ASSEMBLYVERSION and ASSEMBLYFILEVERSION?

Tags: visual-studio, build, versioning, compilation

I need to display both the AssemblyVersion and the AssemblyFileVersion. In AssemblyInfo.cs, I have: 
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("2009.8.0")]

However, I only get "2009.8.0" when I reference the above with:
public class VersionInfo
    {
        public static string AppVersion()
        {
            return System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).FileMajorPart + "." + System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).FileMinorPart + "." + System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).FileBuildPart;
         }
    }

How can I display both values?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Application.ProductVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.productversion.aspx) version will return the AssemblyFileVersion

```
public string AppVersion() 
{ 
  return Application.ProductVersion + "." + 
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
}
```