# information from exe file

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an exe file simpleservice.exe in the physical path F:\SAMPLEPRODUCT\Bin ,, i need to fetch version number of that exe file,,Can you give the code required to fetch the version number

Comment: What language is simpleservice.exe written in?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111541/how-to-reference-both-assemblyversion-and-assemblyfileversion

Comment: Or if you just want to see it in explorer? Then right click and go to properties | details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use the following to do this:

```
Assembly.LoadFrom("...").GetName().Version.ToString();
```

or I'd use the FileVersionInfo class. Take your pick:

```
FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("...");
```

Comment: I'd accidentally hit submit and not finished typing in the rest of my comment. I re-edited it to show the bit I missed when I clicked Submit.

Comment: here  inside Assembly.LoadFrom("...") what we need to give physical path of exe or ?

Comment: OK... I would remove the down vote, but there seems to be a bug... "Vote too old to be changed, unless this answer is edited". Sorry :S

Comment: No problem Thomas - I'm not answering them for the votes, so I'm not upset. I really need to remap the hotkeys on my keyboard to prevent these accidental submits - it's the third time I've done this in a couple of days.

Comment: @peter - you need to give the physical path to the exe here.

Answer (score 6):

You can use

[FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.getversioninfo.aspx)

for this

Eg:

```
public void GetFileVersion() {
    // Get the file version for the exe.
    FileVersionInfo myFileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("your_exe_file");

    // Print the file name and version number.
    textBox1.Text = "File: " + myFileVersionInfo.FileDescription + '\n' +
       "Version number: " + myFileVersionInfo.FileVersion;
 }
```

Comment: +1 though won't this only work on the assumption the assembly was generated with fileversion and assemblyversion set to the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

```
FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(@"F:\SAMPLEPRODUCT\Bin\simpleservice.exe");
Console.WriteLine(fvi.FileVersion);
```

Comment: Is there any other way for finding the location of a file means physical path,,Means here 'simpleservice.exe' is in these physical path F:\SAMPLEPRODUCT\Bin
is there any other simple common way for finding path like server.mappath in ASP.NET,because the path will change some times na,if we copy it into different
file

Comment: I don't understand your question... You need to know the file location, if you don't the system can't guess it for you...

Answer (score 1):

```
    AssemblyName anm = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName( 
     "c:\\winnt\\microsoft.net\\framework\\v1.0.3705\\mscorlib.dll");
    // and show its version
    Console.WriteLine(anm.Version.ToString());
```

Comment: yea but he marks the question with winform and C# tag which give me an assumption that he mean .net assembly

Answer (score 1):

```
AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(@"F:\SAMPLEPRODUCT\Bin\simpleservice.exe").Version
```

Comment: Is there any other way for finding the location of a file means physical path,,Means here 'simpleservice.exe' is in these physical path F:\SAMPLEPRODUCT\Bin
is there any other simple common way for finding path like server.mappath in ASP.NET,because the path will change some times na,if we copy it into different
file

Comment: This code is working with One line of code,,more optimized one

Answer (score 1):

```
public string AssemblyVersion
        {
            get
            {
                return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
            }
        }
```