# How to find out Target framework name and version from exe?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have some exe files which has been created using either .net framework 4.5 or .net core 2.1 or .net core 3.1.

I want to get framework name and version information from this DLL using only c# application.

I have written below piece of code which is beneficial and works great with DLL files but not with exe.

```
var dllInformation = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"D:\\MyProgram.dll");
Console.WriteLine(dllInformation.FullName);
Console.WriteLine(dllInformation.ImageRuntimeVersion);
Console.WriteLine(((TargetFrameworkAttribute)dllInformation.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TargetFrameworkAttribute)).First()).FrameworkName);
```

I have also gone through these links but I didn't found them useful for exe files:

[information from exe file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388178/information-from-exe-file)

[Determine .NET Framework version for dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460982/determine-net-framework-version-for-dll)

Please let me know if any suggestions available.

Comment: Exe can be compiled by other compiler, different from used in .NET/.NET Core

Comment: @mjwills I have several solutions which are available there in Azure and I want to know at once that which applications has not been migrated yet in .net core. I have been assigned to migrate all the projects which has not yet been migrated to .net core 3.1

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Yes exe can be compiled by another compiler but exe can be built using .net framework. I want to know anout that only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following program should display the version of the assembly. The program 
 loads two assemblies during runtime using `Assembly.LoadFrom` method. 1) is a .NET Fx assembly and 2) is a .NET Core assembly. It loads both and displays the framework version without issues. This project is in [github](https://github.com/soundarmoorthy/stackoverflow.examples/tree/master/detect-fx-version-62058953). If you are using the github project, you need to have .NET Core 3.1 installled.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Versioning;

namespace net007
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //A .net framwwork dll in the same output fodler
            //as the current executable
            var fxAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("fx.console.app.exe");

            //A .net core dll in the same output fodler
            //as the current executable
            var netCoreAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("core.console.app.dll");

            ShowFrameworkVersion(fxAssembly); //.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2
            ShowFrameworkVersion(netCoreAssembly);//.NETCoreApp,Version = v3.1
        }

        static void ShowFrameworkVersion(Assembly assembly)
        {
            var attributes = assembly.CustomAttributes;
            foreach (var attribute in attributes)
            {
                if (attribute.AttributeType == typeof(TargetFrameworkAttribute))
                {
                    var arg = attribute.ConstructorArguments.FirstOrDefault();
                    if (arg == null)
                        throw new NullReferenceException("Unable to read framework version");
                    Console.WriteLine(arg.Value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Soundararjan I am able to get version information. Can you help me out with framework name as well?

Comment: What would the values of framework name  look like  ?

Comment: .Net core 2.1 or .Net core 3.1 etc.

Comment: It should display the results in the following format which you can  use to find the name of the framework.
.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2
.NETCoreApp,Version = v3.1
When you run the above program what output do you get ?

Comment: @Soundarajan I am getting Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime error for one of the DLLs

Comment: What dll is it ? Can you share the details (or) a small project that i can test ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerShell to detect for the target framework version:

```
$path = "C:\your dll here.dll"
[Reflection.Assembly]::ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom($path).CustomAttributes |
Where-Object {$_.AttributeType.Name -eq "TargetFrameworkAttribute" } | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty ConstructorArguments | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty value
```

Comment: I already mentioned in question that I want to know this only using C# application.

Comment: @ManishJain Okay, so what if I embed the script into your .NET application and call it? is it solve your needs?

Comment: May be it depends upon the successful execution

Comment: OP wanted a C# solution, but PowerShell is easier to use when trying to troubleshoot an already built assembly. Also, the default table output can cut off a lot of values so I prefer "Format-List" instead: `ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom($path).CustomAttributes | Where-Object {$_.AttributeType.Name -eq "TargetFrameworkAttribute" } | Format-List`

Answer (score 0):

This is my full class to get an "Name.exe" target framework.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Versioning;

public class TargetVersionChecker : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public string GetTargetedFrameWork(string exePath)
    {
        Assembly fxAssembly;
        try
        {
            fxAssembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(exePath);
            var targetFrameworkAttribute = fxAssembly.GetCustomAttributesData().FirstOrDefault(x => x.AttributeType == typeof(TargetFrameworkAttribute));
            return targetFrameworkAttribute?.ConstructorArguments.FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // I log here the error but is to specific to our system so I removed it to be more simple code.
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```